# MYSQL don't start

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, centos7

Previously I performed the migration of my database from one directory to another within the server itself (/var/lib/mysql to /mnt/mysql) for lack of space.

When starting the server again, after having changed the /etc/my.cnf with the correct directory it returns me this error:

```
$ systemctl start mysqld

Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And when I run the systemctl status command on the mysqld service it returns me:

```
$ systemctl status mysqld.service

mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Ter 2019-07-16 09:34:44 -03; 44s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 31923 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 31899 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 31923 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "SERVER_BOOTING"
    Error: 13 (Permission Denied)

Jul 16 09:34:43 srvepl.cettro.local systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
Jul 16 09:34:44 srvepl.cettro.local systemd[1]: mysqld.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 16 09:34:44 srvepl.cettro.local systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
Jul 16 09:34:44 srvepl.cettro.local systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Jul 16 09:34:44 srvepl.cettro.local systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
```

If it is permission error, how do I free the server to accept such a directory?

Note: I am using CentOS 7

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching i discovered that the error was the 'enforcing' permission of SELINUX.

The answer to fix this problem is:

`$ sudo setenforce 0`

And the server went up normally.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux or Unix Server then you should check the permissions of the user to access the service. Here I can see that the user which is logged in can't access the service because of the permission problem.

Try with.

```
sudo systemctl start mysqld;
```

Or try `sudo su;`, enter the creds of the superuser and then try to check the service status.

Or login as superuser and then try to start the service.

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Hello Friend! Thanks for your reply but I'm already with the superuser and I tried the `sudo systemctl start mysqld`. Unfortunately the problem persists. Mysql worked fine before I changed the directory.

Comment: Great, nice to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in with root user?
If no, try with sudo.
Otherwise, I think is better to restart your system and try again.
If you aren't expert in linux centos don't manipulate anything.
uninstall mysql and reinstall it.